# For loop with an if else statement Google-apps-script

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

I have sheet. In column A I have simbol ☑ in some cells. I need that active cell moves to cell after last cell with ☑ simbol.
Now code doesn't work as I want. Please help me to change code. Thanks.

Here is my code

```
 function LastCellInCollA() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 1);
  var i
  sheet.setCurrentCell(cell);  
  for (i = 2; i < 146; i++)
    var valuei = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1).getValues();
  {
    if (valuei = "☑️") 
    {  
      sheet.setCurrentCell(sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1));
      i = i + 1;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you need this script to move from the current active cell to the next cell with ☑️ ?

Comment: @ross No. I need that active become cell without symbol ☑I add screenshot http://joxi.ru/brRjK5GUYJ7G1r Please see. Sheet renew som times and quontity of symbol ☑ increase. So I want that script moves active cell to next clear cell after cell with ☑

Comment: I still find difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you actually describe what steps the code should do? Maybe a sheet with a wrong and good example.
Also I don't think that [`setCurrentCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setcurrentcellcell) should be used here. You are only changing [the selected cell in UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcurrentcell)

Comment: @Raserhin Exactly I need change active cell in UI. Here more screenshot http://joxi.ru/J2byBVYsGXGxPm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that checkmark an ASCII symbol or are you using the Google Sheet checkbox?

If you are using the Google Sheet checkbox, then the following script may work for you.

The recommended way is to not hit the sheet in each loop. So the script does the math and goes directly to the relevant cell instead of going row-by-row.

```
function LastCellInCollA() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
  var d = 0;
  while (data[d][0] == true) { d++; } // If you are using ASCII symbol, replace 'true' with the symbol
  var lastRow = d + 2;
  var cell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1);
  sheet.setCurrentCell(cell);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I use exactly simbol ☑